# Having trouble understanding where to look in source code, in order to create a web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am noob with python, been on and off teaching myself since this summer. I am going through the scrapy tutorial, and occasionally reading more about html/xml to help me understand scrapy. My project to myself is to imitate the scrapy tutorial in order to scrape http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/916373-pc. I want to get a list of the thread title along with the thread url, should be simple!

My problem lies in not understanding xpath, and also html i guess. When viewing the source code for the gamefaqs site, I am not sure what to look for in order to pull the link and title. I want to say just look at the anchor tag and grab the text, but i am confused on how.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "dmoz"
allowed_domains = ["http://www.gamefaqs.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/916373-pc"]


def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//a')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = DmozItem()
        item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

I want to change this to work on gamefaqs, so what would i put in this path? 
I imagine the program returning results something like this
thread name
thread url
I know the code is not really right but can someone help me rewrite this to obtain the results, it would help me understand the scraping process better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout and organization of a web page can change and deep tag based paths can be difficult to deal with. I prefer to pattern match the text of the links. Even if the link format changes, matching the new pattern is simple.

For gamefaqs the article links look like:

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/916373-pc/37644384

That's the protocol, domain name, literal 'boards' path. '916373-pc' identifies the forum area and '37644384' is the article ID.

We can match links for a specific forum area using using a regular expression:

```
reLink = re.compile(r'.*\/boards\/916373-pc\/\d+$')
if reLink.match(link)
```

Or any forum area using using:

```
reLink = re.compile(r'.*\/boards\/\d+-[^/]+\/\d+$')
if reLink.match(link)
```

Adding link matching to your code we get:

```
import re
reLink = re.compile(r'.*\/boards\/\d+-[^/]+\/\d+$')

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//a')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        link = site.select('a/@href').extract()
        if reLink.match(link)
            item = DmozItem()
            item['link'] = link
            item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
    return items
```

Many sites have separate summary and detail pages or description and file links where the paths match a template with an article ID. If needed, you can parse the forum area and article ID like this:

```
reLink = re.compile(r'.*\/boards\/(?P<area>\d+-[^/]+)\/(?P<id>\d+)$')
m = reLink.match(link)
if m:
    areaStr = m.groupdict()['area']
    idStr = m.groupdict()['id']
```

`isStr` will be a string which is fine for filling in a URL template, but if you need to calculate the previous ID, etc., then convert it to a number:

```
idInt = int(idStr)
```

I hope this helps.