# Android get result generated from Python

Tags: android, python

Since I am a starter of Python, I just written some code for grab some text in a long string.
Normally, for the client-server communication, I use PHP as server side language.
After Google Python, I know that in some ways, Python will run faster than PHP for example to get all link in a HTML.
Using PHP, I know that I can using regular expression to extract all links in HTML and generate the results as JSON and get back to Android side using HTTP.
The question is, how can I do it in Python way/?
I really had no experience with python in server. Is it possible to do that?
If yes, please give some hint.

Comment: You can do in Python what you want. But what is your main question? How to get links out of HTML document using Python? What are you passing to the server that you need get links out of HTML? Apparently not a query string of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to scrub the links from a page as described in this old answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465097/514485

Python has a JSON module that makes it easy to format your results in JSON.

Comment: Btw, it's JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), not JASON.

Comment: but how can I get the result from python? I need to run python in apache server?

Comment: @jjLin, are you asking how to configure Apache to support Python? See: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html. Generally mod_wsgi is the current best practice. If that's not available, on a shared host for example, then FastCGI can be a good choice. While I personally really liked mod_python, it's fallen out of favor and has not be actively developed for quite some time. If you're coming from PHP, note that Python is frequently used with a least a light web framework.